# Can anyone help me with the crash? (React Native)

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, crash

The app crashed when I just stay in it for over 1 hour. I did not do anything else beside staying in it. I have no idea what this log is trying to tell me so if anyone can help me I would appreciate it a lot.
This is the crash log

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  29

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1856a186c __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19a6bcc50 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   unikapp                         0x1002f52ac RCTFatal + 668 (RCTAssert.m:146)
3   unikapp                         0x100374e7c -[RCTExceptionsManager reportFatal:stack:exceptionId:suppressRedBox:] + 504 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:78)
4   unikapp                         0x1003758d0 -[RCTExceptionsManager reportException:] + 1532 (RCTExceptionsManager.mm:148)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1856a68f4 __invoking___ + 148
6   CoreFoundation                  0x18557ddf8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 448 (NSForwarding.m:3389)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x18557e3cc -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 80 (NSForwarding.m:3495)
8   unikapp                         0x10032780c -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 460 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
9   unikapp                         0x100329e18 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) + 540 (RCTNativeModule.mm:183)
10  unikapp                         0x100329a48 operator() + 68 (RCTNativeModule.mm:104)
11  unikapp                         0x100329a48 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 112 (RCTNativeModule.mm:95)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x18529424c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1454)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x185295db0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:559)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x18529d10c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580 (inline_internal.h:2548)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x18529dc5c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408 (queue.c:3862)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x1852a7d78 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708 (queue.c:6601)
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1d1151814 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2211)
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x1d115876c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 29 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b35f6414 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d1150b50 pthread_kill + 272 (pthread.c:1392)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018eacfb74 abort + 104 (abort.c:110)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019a7c2cf8 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:76)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019a7b3e4c demangling_terminate_handler() + 308 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:67)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019a6bcf64 _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019a7c20e0 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019a7c206c std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000185295dc4 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:562)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018529d10c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 580 (inline_internal.h:2548)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018529dc5c _dispatch_lane_invoke + 408 (queue.c:3862)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001852a7d78 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 708 (queue.c:6601)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d1151814 _pthread_wqthread + 276 (pthread.c:2211)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d115876c start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: were you able to fix it ?